# 415 Unsupported Media Type what does it mean

Tags: jquery

```
$( "#teacher-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
            "Create an account":function(){
        $.ajax({
             url: 'newteacher',
                 type: 'POST',
                 contentType: 'application/json',
                 data: { json: JSON.stringify({
                     name:"Bob",
                     email:"xyz@xyz.com"
                 })
            },
    });
```

Comment: Looks like you have a missing `)` on the second-last line. Your 415 error is coming back from your server though, what's happening with `newteacher`?

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten some closing statments.

try this

```
$( "#teacher-form" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
height: 300,
width: 350,
modal: true,
buttons: {                                             //button start
        "Create an account":function(){                //function start
            $.ajax({                                   //ajax start
               url: 'newteacher',
               type: 'POST',
               contentType: 'application/json',
               data: {                                 //data start
                     json: JSON.stringify({            //json start
                          name:"Bob",
                          email:"xyz@xyz.com"
                     })                                //json end
               }                                       //data end
            });                                         //ajax end
         }                                             //function end
   }                                                   //button end
});
```